# Como puedo desestructurar este Json de 3 array a 2 array?

Tags: javascript, json

tengo el siguiente problema, lo que pasa es que ando intentado desestructurar este json de este formato:

```html
[
    [
        [
            {
                "Country": "Denmark",
                "Province": "Faroe Islands",
                "Date": "06-12-2020",
                "Long": "-6.9118",
                "Lat": "61.89263",
                "Confirmed": 188,
                "Deaths": 0,
                "Recovered": 8432
            },
            {
                "Country": "Denmark",
                "Province": "Faroe Islands",
                "Date": "07-12-2020",
                "Long": "-6.9118",
                "Lat": "61.8926",
                "Confirmed": 188,
                "Deaths": 0,
                "Recovered": 842
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Country": "Denmark",
                "Province": "Greenland",
                "Date": "06-12-2020",
                "Long": "-42.6043",
                "Lat": "71.7069",
                "Confirmed": 132,
                "Deaths": 0,
                "Recovered": 1027
            },
            {
                "Country": "Denmark",
                "Province": "Greenland",
                "Date": "06-12-2020",
                "Long": "-42.6043",
                "Lat": "71.7069",
                "Confirmed": 13,
                "Deaths": 0,
                "Recovered": 107
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "Country": "France",
                "Province": "Martinique",
                "Date": "06-12-2020",
                "Long": "-61.0242",
                "Lat": "14.6415",
                "Confirmed": 22525,
                "Deaths": 15,
                "Recovered": 1374
            },
            {
                "Country": "France",
                "Province": "Martinique",
                "Date": "07-12-2020",
                "Long": "-61.0242",
                "Lat": "14.6415",
                "Confirmed": 2525,
                "Deaths": 15,
                "Recovered": 1374
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Country": "France",
                "Province": "",
                "Date": "06-12-2020",
                "Long": "2.2137",
                "Lat": "46.2276",
                "Confirmed": 198183,
                "Deaths": 29909,
                "Recovered": 4214
            },
            {
                "Country": "France",
                "Province": "",
                "Date": "07-12-2020",
                "Long": "2.2137",
                "Lat": "46.2276",
                "Confirmed": 198183,
                "Deaths": 29909,
                "Recovered": 4214
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

a estructurarlo a este formato

```js
[
    [
        {
            "Country": "Denmark",
            "Province": "Faroe Islands",
            "Date": "06-12-2020",
            "Long": "-6.9118",
            "Lat": "61.89263",
            "Confirmed": 188,
            "Deaths": 0,
            "Recovered": 8432
        },
        {
            "Country": "Denmark",
            "Province": "Faroe Islands",
            "Date": "07-12-2020",
            "Long": "-6.9118",
            "Lat": "61.8926",
            "Confirmed": 188,
            "Deaths": 0,
            "Recovered": 842
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Country": "Denmark",
            "Province": "Greenland",
            "Date": "06-12-2020",
            "Long": "-42.6043",
            "Lat": "71.7069",
            "Confirmed": 132,
            "Deaths": 0,
            "Recovered": 1027
        },
        {
            "Country": "Denmark",
            "Province": "Greenland",
            "Date": "06-12-2020",
            "Long": "-42.6043",
            "Lat": "71.7069",
            "Confirmed": 13,
            "Deaths": 0,
            "Recovered": 107
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Country": "France",
            "Province": "Martinique",
            "Date": "06-12-2020",
            "Long": "-61.0242",
            "Lat": "14.6415",
            "Confirmed": 22525,
            "Deaths": 15,
            "Recovered": 1374
        },
        {
            "Country": "France",
            "Province": "Martinique",
            "Date": "07-12-2020",
            "Long": "-61.0242",
            "Lat": "14.6415",
            "Confirmed": 2525,
            "Deaths": 15,
            "Recovered": 1374
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Country": "France",
            "Province": "",
            "Date": "06-12-2020",
            "Long": "2.2137",
            "Lat": "46.2276",
            "Confirmed": 198183,
            "Deaths": 29909,
            "Recovered": 4214
        },
        {
            "Country": "France",
            "Province": "",
            "Date": "07-12-2020",
            "Long": "2.2137",
            "Lat": "46.2276",
            "Confirmed": 198183,
            "Deaths": 29909,
            "Recovered": 4214
        }
    ]
]
```

Lo que ha cambiado es que ya no se encuentra en de 3 array para llegar a los objectos, si no a 2 array para llegar a los objecto.

Mis intento de soluccion fueron esta:

```
console.log([...jsonData[0], ...jsonData[1]]);
```

El codigo de arriba me funciona, pero el unico incoveniente es que tengo que agregar todo manual, lo intente hacerlo con un map, no fue la soluccion aun me seguia creando los 3 array

```
const hola =  Object.keys(jsonData).map((keys) =>[ ...jsonData[keys]))
```

Llevo una parte de la tarde en esto, Gracias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe la funcion `flat`, la cual permite aquello que indicas y nos hace la vida sumamente facil, vamos a usarla para poder resolver tu problema:

```js
const data = 
[
  [
    [{
        "Country": "Denmark",
        "Province": "Faroe Islands",
        "Date": "06-12-2020",
        "Long": "-6.9118",
        "Lat": "61.89263",
        "Confirmed": 188,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 8432
      },
      {
        "Country": "Denmark",
        "Province": "Faroe Islands",
        "Date": "07-12-2020",
        "Long": "-6.9118",
        "Lat": "61.8926",
        "Confirmed": 188,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 842
      }
    ],
    [{
        "Country": "Denmark",
        "Province": "Greenland",
        "Date": "06-12-2020",
        "Long": "-42.6043",
        "Lat": "71.7069",
        "Confirmed": 132,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 1027
      },
      {
        "Country": "Denmark",
        "Province": "Greenland",
        "Date": "06-12-2020",
        "Long": "-42.6043",
        "Lat": "71.7069",
        "Confirmed": 13,
        "Deaths": 0,
        "Recovered": 107
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [{
        "Country": "France",
        "Province": "Martinique",
        "Date": "06-12-2020",
        "Long": "-61.0242",
        "Lat": "14.6415",
        "Confirmed": 22525,
        "Deaths": 15,
        "Recovered": 1374
      },
      {
        "Country": "France",
        "Province": "Martinique",
        "Date": "07-12-2020",
        "Long": "-61.0242",
        "Lat": "14.6415",
        "Confirmed": 2525,
        "Deaths": 15,
        "Recovered": 1374
      }
    ],
    [{
        "Country": "France",
        "Province": "",
        "Date": "06-12-2020",
        "Long": "2.2137",
        "Lat": "46.2276",
        "Confirmed": 198183,
        "Deaths": 29909,
        "Recovered": 4214
      },
      {
        "Country": "France",
        "Province": "",
        "Date": "07-12-2020",
        "Long": "2.2137",
        "Lat": "46.2276",
        "Confirmed": 198183,
        "Deaths": 29909,
        "Recovered": 4214
      }
    ]
  ]
]

const flatData = data.flat();
console.log(flatData);
```

Como vemos ahora esta dentro de 2 arrays en vez de 3. muy sencillo la verdad.

Porcierto, lo que intentas **no se llama destructuracion**, se llama **flatmap**.

Comment: Wao, tengo un poco mas de 2 anios programando con js nunca habia escuchado de esta funcion, de igual manera lo resolvi con varios map por que se esta programando con node 10. y esta funcion es minimo node 11